# Convert a PDA to a CFG

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar

My professor doesn't do a very good job at explaining the process of converting a PDA to a CFG. Can someone help explain it?

The way I see it (but it produces wrong results) is each production is created by an instruction. And if it is a push instruction, then the production is the items on the stack plus the input symbol. And if it is a pop instruction, then the symbol is just the input symbol.

So `(a,X)/push(a)` would produce `X --> aAX`

Then say I had `b,a/pop` would produce `A --> b`

I have an example problem. I believe the correct solution is

```
S --> $lambda$ | aSa | bSb
```

[image]

Comment: It is a bit hard for us to know the details of "the algorithm shown in class". There are a lot of possible ways to connect the dots here, and exactly how your teacher has chosen to present it is next to impossible to guess.

Comment: @HenningMakholm considering he didn't really explain it, I was hoping to find any way to do it. That is, in terms of the notation used. So some way similar to the way I explained my solution (which is incorrect)